# Mapping Dto to Entity for DataGrid consumption

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, dto

I am writing a WPF MVVM app and have a question about mapping from Database Dto objects to Model entities.

First up, I am not using an ORM for this project (EF or NH etc.) - so there is just a Oracle Repository with methods that return Dto Collections i.e.

```
private IList<MyDataDto> LoadData(){
...
}
```

MyDataDto might look like this:

```
public class MyDataDto
{
    public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
}
```

MyDataEntity might look like this:

```
public class MyDataEntity
{
    public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }

    public decimal? Toyota { get; set; }

    public decimal? Honda { get; set; }

    public decimal? Nissan { get; set; }

    public decimal? Mazda { get; set; } 
}
```

and my model like so:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IEnumerable<MyDataEntity> modelData;
    public IEnumerable<MyDataEntity> ModelData
    {
        get { return modelData; }
        set
        {
            modelData= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ModelData");
        }
    }

    //other stuff in here but not shown for brevity
}
```

I have a Quartz scheduler running and in that job it queries the database and a custom mapper maps the Dto collection to the Entity collection and then assigns the Entity collection to the Model which inherits from the INotifyPropertyChanged interface so the changes are reflected in my UI.

Each Identifier value in the MyDataDto, equals a Property in MyDataEntity. So if a valid Identifer value is Toyota, the column name in the MyDataEntity would be Toyota. These Identifiers are already specified in the query where clause (they have to be), so I know what Identifiers will be retrieved, and these will unlikely change (extremely unlikely!)

So, my question is this, is it ok to have an ugly entity like I have shown (with the Identifers as column names) so that mapping to the datagrid is easy, or is there is better, more preferred way?

Comment: I should say the MyDataDto is basically the same as how the data is stored in the database, so it's just a very simple traverse thorugh the dataset to fill the dto

Comment: I should also say, if it wasn't clear, that the datagrid has the date as a row header and the Identifiers as column headers

Comment: Are you sure that the changes are reflected in your UI? E.g. With your implementation, I would have thought that if you changed the decimal? properties of your DataEntity, it would not be updated since the class does not implement INPC and your Model class doesn't wrap your Entity

Comment: Yea, positive. My model is injected into the constructor which then adds the event model.PropertyChanged += OnModelChanged; - In the OnModelChanged event I assign the model to a public property of type ObservableCollection<MyDataEntity> which my datagrid is bound too

Comment: my vm also implements INotifyPropertyChanged for the ObservableCollection<MyDataEntity> - this doesn't really need to be a ObservableCollection, but meh

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
public class MyDataEntity
{
    public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<Identifier, decimal?> IdentifierType { get; set; } 
}

public enum Identifer
{
    Toyota,
    Honda,
    Nissan,
    Mazda
}
```

and in my xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding IdentifierType[Toyota]}" />
```

my mapper takes care of the transformation from dto to model entity and the result makes my model much tidier, and works beautifully!

Hopefully this helps other xaml/wpf noobs